# Who and how many times accessed Hive tables

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, impala

I want to know how many times my hive tables are accessed.
The details I would like to get here are, the tableName and how many times it was accessed. Eg:-

| tableName | No.Of Access |
| --- | --- |
| Table1 | 100 |
| Table2 | 80 |
| .... | .... |
| Table n | n |

**Is there any Hive/Linux command/code to do so? Also, I tried to understand the last access time of my table using**

```
describe formatted database.table
```

But it shows me

| Name | type |
| --- | --- |
| 'LastAccessTime: | 'UNKNOWN |

Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i doubt that will be saved in a database

Comment: AFAIK in a secure Hadoop environment, capturing this kind of audit information would require a separate auxiliary service, something like Apache Ranger or Cloudera Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your [hive audit log](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-AuditLogs).

> Audit Logs Audit logs are logged from the Hive metastore server for
> every metastore API invocation.
>
> An audit log has the function and some of the relevant function
> arguments logged in the metastore log file. It is logged at the INFO
> level of log4j, so you need to make sure that the logging at the INFO
> level is enabled (see HIVE-3505). The name of the log entry is
> "HiveMetaStore.audit".
>
> Audit logs were added in Hive 0.7 for secure client connections
> (HIVE-1948) and in Hive 0.10 for non-secure connections (HIVE-3277;
> also see HIVE-2797).

There is also [HDFS audit logs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/HowToConfigure) that you could use to derive access to hive tables.

If you have Ranger enabled that is your best bet to help see who is access what.